# Show diferent presentation on small screens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive

I have simple web presentation (html+css) old site, no mobile frendly, and just would like to show some simple bootstrap onepage presentatio on small devices ( less 920px), so idea is if screen is less then 920px to show that new presentation,make site mobile frendly, and my option is:

1.Using JS/Jquery to redirect user on new page or subdomain if he use small screens

any other ideas would be helpful..

Best regards,

Pavle

Answer (score 1):

```
use media query
<div class="static" style="height:300px;width:100%">
</div>
<div class="dynamic">
</div>
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.dynamic{
  height:100px;
  } 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.dynamic{
  height:200px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.dynamic{
  height:300px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.dynamic{
  height:400px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.dynamic{
  height:500px;
  } 
}
```